# How to develop an AAC converter for Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, converters, aac

I am a beginner developer want to develop a MP3 to AAC converter for Linux. But I don't know how to start as I havn't done any development in Linux before. I am using Ubuntu 10.04. Can anyone tell me how to start and from where? What libraries do I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an encoder, [FAAC](http://www.audiocoding.com/downloads.html) is open source, so you could write a program that uses it.  Or check out the source code.

[I.A.N.A.L.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL) but, [AAC is a patented technology](http://www.vialicensing.com/Licensing/AAC_fees.cfm), so you may have to pay fees to make a commercial project.

A good place to start learning how lots of Unix programs are written, is using the [GNU toolchain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_toolchain), [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), [Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/), [Configure](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) etc...

Answer (score 0):

The ffmpeg libraries are a great swiss army knife for anything dealing with audio/video.  In fact, you can use the ffmpeg command-line interface to easily convert between MP3 and AAC:

```
ffmpeg -i <path to MP3 file> <path to AAC file>
```

This requires that ffmpeg be compiled with FAAC and LAME support.  I don't think Ubuntu's ffmpeg libraries include these by default for legal reasons, but there are ways to install MP3 and AAC enabled versions: http://gebaar.blogspot.com/2009/06/howto-easily-enable-mp3-mpeg4-aac-and.html

If you want to use ffmpeg's underlying libraries (libavcodec, libavformat, etc) to code it yourself: http://cekirdek.pardus.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/api-example_8c-source.html